# Carregar informações de um JS para PHP

Tags: php, javascript, formulário

Preciso pegar a informação de um arquivo JS (form.js) e carregar em um arquivo PHP (mail.php).

No arquivo form.js existe uma função que calcula o valor da entrega com base nos grupos de CEP. Aqui é a variavel dela:

```
var taxadeentrega = total - taxa;
```

Segue abaixo um trecho do código para o seu entendimento:

```
//aqui eu pego o cep
var cep = document.getElementById("cep").value;

//verifica se deve incrementar ou não
if(cep == "20010-090" || cep == "20020-100" || cep == "20021-130" || cep == "20021-315" || cep == "20030-901" || cep == "20030-021" || cep == "20210-030" || cep == "24220-280"){               
    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 1.2 no valor final
    taxa = 1.50;            
}
if(cep == "20020-010"|| cep == "22050-032" || cep == "20020-040" || cep == "20020-080" || cep == "20030-905" || cep == "24220-031" || cep == "20002-010" || cep == "20030-015"){
    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 0.7 no valor final
    taxa = 1.00;            
}

total += taxa;

if(taxa != 0){
    //caso a taxa seja diferente de 0, mostra ao usuário
    document.getElementById("idTaxa").innerHTML = "Custo adicional: R$ " + taxa;
}
```

Esse é o valor da entrega, preciso que essa informação seja carregada no meu arquivo mail.php onde hoje ele puxa direto do campo formulário assim:

```
$entrega = $_POST["taxadeentrega"];
```

Preciso dessa informação corretamente para aplica em outra regra.
Ou seja, resumindo: Preciso que `$entrega = VALOR_DA_TAXA` que será puxando do arquivo form.js

Comment: Se o recebimento é por um `POST`, deve haver um envio de formulário  para o recebimento ou, um envio **AJAX** para a página PHP. Há essas tratativas?

Comment: Pode utilizar método GET?

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia enviar o formulário via post, mas se quiser tratar diretamente JS e PHP, você pode utilizar `AJAX`, abaixo um exemplo com jQuery:

```
$.post("mail.php", {taxadeentrega: taxa})
.done(function(data){
    // CASO TENHA CONCLUIDO
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function(data){
    // CASO TENHA FALHADO
});
```

**PS:** Se for usar o Javascript puro, acesse [essa referência.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Obrigado Anderson pela atenção, mas não entendi! Coloco aonde? No arquivo em JS ou PHP, sou leigo em programação.

Comment: é um script JS, mas pra você utilizar esse script precisa usar o jQuery. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` coloque essa tag dentro do <head> no seu projeto